# Не проходит компиляция из-за ошибок

Tags: c++, borland-c++

Задание: Два прямоугольника расположенные в первом квадранте, со сторонами параллельными осям координат, заданы координатами своих левого верхнего и 9 правого нижнего углов. Для первого прямоугольника это точки (x1, y1) и (x2, 0), для второго - (x3, y3) и (x4, 0). Составить программу, определяющую, пресекаются ли данные прямоугольники, и вычисляющую площадь общей части, если они пересекаются

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std; //здесь выдает ошибку Declaration Syntax Error
int main(){
 double x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y3
 if (x1>x2 || x3>x4) //здесь выдает ошибку Declaration Syntax Error
 cout<<"ошибка в задании координат";
 if (x3 < x2 && x4 > x1)
 {
 double yp= min(y1, y3); //здесь выдает ошибку Function 'min' should have a prototype
 double xp1= max(x1, x3); //здесь выдает ошибку Function max' should have a prototype
 double xp2= min(x2, x4);
 double s=(xp2 - xp1)*yp;
 cout<<s;
 }
 else
 cout<<"не пересекаются";
 getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: В плюсах заголовочный файл без расширения `#include <iostream>`. Ошибка : точку с запятой пропустили : `double x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y3;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe В борланде с `.h`, хотя плюсами это назвать сложно.

Comment: в Borland C++ v3.1 нет algorithms.h

Comment: Эм.. Его там действительно нет, но его нет ни у тебя в вопросе, ни в одном сообщении или комментарии на странице (даже в удалённых). Что оно тут делает?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> using namespace std; //здесь выдает ошибку Declaration Syntax Error
> ```

Удали эту строку, она не нужна.

> ```
> double x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y3
> ```

Добавь в конец `;`.

> ```
> double yp= min(y1, y3); //здесь выдает ошибку Function 'min' should have a prototype
>  double xp1= max(x1, x3); //здесь выдает ошибку Function max' should have a prototype
> ```

По идее должны быть в `stdlib.h`, но если после исправления предыдущих ошибок не заработает, то придётся реализовать их самостоятельно.

Ещё можно попробовать `fmin` из `math.h`, но что-то я сомневаюсь, что он там был.

Comment: По рекомендации выше "using namespace std; //здесь выдает ошибку Declaration Syntax Error
Удали эту строку, она не нужна."
я сделал так и..
И О ЧУДО!!! ошибка пропала и всё заработало.
ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, не только я запнулся на пространстве имён С++, поэтому разрешите предоставить объяснение Герберта Шилдта в книге "С++. Руководство для начинающих":
Приложение Б. Использование устаревшего С++ компилятора.
При использовании современного компилятора у вас не должно быть проблем с компиляцией программ из этой книги. В этом случае вам вообще не понадобится информация, представленная в настоящем приложении. Как разъяснялось выше, программы, приведенные в этой книге, полностью соответствуют стандарту ANSI/ IS0 для С++ и могут быть скомпилированы практически любым современным С++-компилятором, включая Visual С++ (Мiсrosoft) и С++ Builder (Borland).
Но если вы используете компилятор, созданный несколько лет назад, то при попытке скомпилировать наши примеры он может выдать целый список ошибок,
не распознав ряд новых С++-средств. И в этом случае не стоит волноваться. Для того чтобы эти программы заработали со старыми компиляторами, нужно внести
в них небольшие изменения. Чаще всего старые и новые С++-программы отличаются использованием двух средств: заголовков и npoстранств имен."
Я покороче опишу:
(ОШИБКА: "using namespace std; //здесь выдает ошибку Declaration Syntax Error")
Новая версия компилятора не требует указывать расширение имён файлов заголовков(.h), НО ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО требуется объявлять пространство имён std.
ЕСЛИ У ВАС ПРИ КОМПИЛЯЦИИ возникают ошибки с указанием на эти строки, ЗНАЧИТ У ВАС СТАРАЯ ВЕРСИЯ КОМПИЛЯТОРА, и ему надо указывать так:

#include <iostream.h> // указываем расширение имени файла заголовков .h

// using namespace std;  - исключаем строку, объявляющую область пространства имён языка С++, необходимых для новой версии языка и компилятора.